# a continuous Function adds a function with intermediate value property

Tags: real-analysis

If a function $f(x)$ has intermediate value property while $g(x)$ is a continuous Function, then will $h(x)=f(x)+g(x)$,  have intermediate value property?

If we can find $F(x)$ that $f(x)=F'(x)$, the answer is yes. But is it true for all $f(x)$ having intermediate value property?